# Create text files, compress them to a ZipArchive and present it for download

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, zip, export-to-csv

my scenario:

1. asp.net mvc web application
2. User clicks on a button in a view to start the action

Action:

1. Create several csv files from records that are stored in tables of an sql db
2. Compress all created files into a single ZipArchive
3. Present the ZipArchive for download to the client computer

I have a working code for creating a single csv file and presenting it for download.

```
    public class ExportCSVController : BaseController
    {

    public ExportCSVController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
    public void ExportCSV_Company()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var companies = UnitOfWork.GetAll<Company>();
        var list = companies.ToList();
        sb.AppendFormat("{0};{1};{2}{3};{4}", "Name", "Street", "City", "Zipcode", Environment.NewLine);
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4}", "\"" + item.Name + "\"", item.Street, item.City, item.Zip, Environment.NewLine);
        }
        //Get Current Response
        var response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.BufferOutput = true;
        response.Clear();
        response.ClearHeaders();
        response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
        response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Companies.txt ");
        response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        response.Write(sb.ToString());
        response.End();
    }
    }
```

I also have a working code for compressing a file to a ZipArchive  (using System.IO.Compression).

My idea:

- Set up a loop (in my working code) for each file that needs to be generated
- after generating the first file, add the file to the ZipArchive (using System.IO.Compression)
- continue with the next file generation and append the file to the ZipArchive ...
- then present the ZipArchive for download

My problem:

- I do not quite understand where in the given code the file is generated, if at all?
  I think, that response.Write() just directs the generated string to the browser where finally it is converted to a file when the user clicks on save.

Questions:

1. Must the response be saved to a file before it can be added to a ZipArchive?

If yes,

1. How would I convert the response via code to a file?
2. Is there any way to skip writing a physical file in order to get it into the ZipArchive?

Comment: Your understanding is correct, this code doesnt make a file it tells the browser to receive a file and sends contents

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below, my example solution (for zipping 2 files)

```
public void ExportFilesToZip()
{
    string zipFileName = "Test.zip";
    string firstFileName = "FirstFile.txt";
    string secondFileName = "SecondFile.txt";
    string firstFileContent ="1";
    string secondFileContent ="2";

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + zipFileName);

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            var demoFile = archive.CreateEntry(firstFileName);

            using (var entryStream = demoFile.Open())
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(firstFileContent);
            }

            demoFile = archive.CreateEntry(secondFileName);

            using (var entryStream = demoFile.Open())
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(secondFileContent);
            }
        }

        using (var fileStream = Response.OutputStream)
        {
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }

    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: This solution was exactly what I was looking for. I was able to easily adapt the "firstFile" and "secondFile" to use the loops that I am working with. Thanks!